# How to create a game save in java using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, save

I'm creating a simple clicker game (you know the ones where you click something and it adds to the total score) and I'm trying to make it so that when you exit, all of your progress is saved, and not deleted. I have searched for how to make a game save, player data, and have still not found anything to help! if you do know, and could help me, that would be much appreciated!

Comment: Just create a txt file with your game data.

Comment: that's a rather broad question. the simplest way of writing objects to a file in java would be `ObjectOutputStream`. But in general the way of saving the state is highly dependent upon the data-structure used in the program

Comment: How exactly would I use this for Booleans, integers, and the overall progress